# Virtual Host With Proxypass

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, apache2

When I try to open URL tissue.example.com, it will show tissue.example.com/tissue/index.php (the requested URL was not found)

When I type tissue.example.com/index.php it will show the page but almost CSS file and image not showing. The image load with tissue.example.com/tissue/image.jpg

hopefully someone can help me

My virtual host config

```
<VirtualHost  *:80>

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.10/tissue/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.10/tissue/

ServerName tissue.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What kidn of page are you using, please wrote more context as currently you using a Reverse-Proxy that access already the Subfolder - either remove /tissue from the Reverse-Proxy or keep it and fix your CSS files

Comment: i am using joomla.... i have main web apache server... the virtual host at the server but the joomla installation is in other server... that why i use proxypass

Comment: how do you want to get your site showing, with url/ orurl/tissue?

Comment: tissue.example.com will redirect to tissue.example.com/tissue/index.php. will show url not found
when i type tissue.example.com/index.php will show the page but error 404 for css file or image location.

Comment: then fix joomla, your site then was setup to use /tissue instead of /